Question on animal deaths in Middle Grade novels
I am a self published author just finishing the fourth book in a five book series. The story heavily features guinea pigs, and the main characters are a girl and her dad, whose consciousness merges with her pet guinea pig.
There is a scene I want to include, I'm just not sure if it's too dark / too far for a children's book. At the end, a bad character intentionally steps on a guinea pig, killing it. It is a key incident in the book and several plot and character elements nicely tie into it. Because of this, it's really difficult for me to remove.
What do you guys think? Is it too far, or is it OK?

Children in your target age group understand death.  Novels that target that age, like Mrs. Frisby and the Rats of NIHM, The Tale of Despereaux, Bridge to Terabithia, all deal with death as a major plot element.
If the rodent needs to die for the story, then kill the rodent. If stepping on the rodent is important, then stomp away. Don't describe it graphically. It doesn't have to be shown. It can just be stated. The characters can react to the event. It can be very powerful, if written that way.

This seems too extreme for a Middle Grade novel. Middle Grade novels must not contain any graphic violence. Remember, you are writing for kids between 10 and 13 years of age. Most children love animals, and stepping on one to kill it will shock many of them profoundly.

Thanks, I think you're probably right. But how do I reconcile that with, for example, something like Bambi?

@MarkStevenson Bambi is not a contemporary MG novel, it is a 1942 animated movie. Death in Disney movies has been widely discussed. There are scholarly analyses of their effect on the children watching them. Look those articles up, if you are interested.
